# data type conversion to BIG_INT in odbc driver

Tags: sql, c, odbc

How do I convert a datatype of SQL_INTEGER to SQL_C_BIGINT?

I have an odbc driver that is used by power BI to interact with a datasource.
During the call SQLColAttribute, the driver passes the column type as SIGNED SQL_INTEGER.
However, when the SQLFetchData is called by the client, it is expecting the datatype to be
SQL_C_BIGINT.
So basically, I want to convert the data of type SQL_INTEGER to SQL_C_BIGINT before passing it back to the client(power bi).

The challenge I am having is that I am not able to get the format in which a  SQL_C_BIGINT is expected in the driver. If I do a simple cast, the data is appearing incorrectly in the client.

```
SQLRETURN SQLGetData(SQLHSTMT StatementHandle,
                             SQLUSMALLINT ColumnNumber, SQLSMALLINT TargetType,
                             SQLPOINTER TargetValue, SQLLEN BufferLength,
                             SQLLEN  *StrLen_or_Ind)
{
     //TargetType is SQL_C_BIGINT
     // Assuming that I have my data in p, how do I copy it to TargetValue so that it is read as SQL_C_BIGINT by the client???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL_C_BIGINT is basically an 8 byte integer. All I had to do is assign the value to _int64 variable and pass it back.